# What is the meaning of 背会?

Tags: verbs

I have encountered the following sentences in my textbook, which use `背会`.

> 我还没背会这篇文章。
>
> 今天不背会这篇课文就不回家。

But what does `背会` mean? The textbook seems to say it means `memorize`, but of all the dictionaries I have and from the result I googled, it seems that there is no word registered as `背会`.

Anyone can clarify it...?

Comment: 会 can function as complement of result, thus can follow any number of verbs, e.g. 学会，念会

Comment: @S.Rhee So `会` functions as an aspect particle? If `会` functions as an auxiliary verb here, isn't it `会背`, not `背会`, right?

Comment: agreed, complement of result （结果补语），aspect particle （动态助词）(着，过，了，的，在），会 may function as auxiliary verb (助动词）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

背会 and 会背 are not the same.

背会 verb + result, memorize/recite it until you know it (by heart)

会背 auxiliary verb + verb, able to recite from memory

我还没背会这篇文章。

I still have not learned this essay by heart yet.

今天不背会这篇课文就不回家。

I won't go home until I've learned this text by heart today.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So grammatically, `会` in this case works as complements of result, right?

Answer (score -2):

会 - in this context, it is translated as "can", "be able to"

背 - in this context, it is translated as "remember"

背会 can be used as 会背, which both are the same, if that makes more sense to you

Comment: lol, reading who wrote this answer freaked me out a little bit -_-

Comment: I was trying to help, but looks like i got it wrong here , they are different .. :D